# Is it possible to pass sprintf type arguments to a Perl function?

Tags: perl

Consider the following sample code.

```
my $a = "test";
my $b = "stackoverflow";

test("%s - %s\n", $a, $b);

sub test {
    my $error = sprintf(@_);
    print $error;
}
```

This prints 3 and not a formatted string. Is it even possible to do what I'm trying?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As VGE suggested, it's the prototype that's causing problems, but you need to use `shift`, not `pop`:

```
sub test {
    my $error = sprintf(shift, @_);
    print $error;
}
```

`sprintf` evaluates its first argument in scalar context.  If that's an array, you get the length of the array.

Answer (score 1):

perldoc says 
sprintf FORMAT, LIST

Returns a string formatted by the usual printf conventions of the C library function sprintf. See below for more details and see sprintf(3) or printf(3) on your system for an explanation of the general principles.

I never try this but, I think you can try to pop @_ to get the format and pass the remaining list after.

Comment: I know how sprintf works but what I can't get to work is when I'm passing tbe format and elements to the sub routine to do the formatting inside. Separating the format and the elements doesn't make a difference, sprintf(@_) does the same thing as that.